# Alternative proof for this formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, mobius-function

Using a very complicated argument, I believe I can prove:

$$ 1 = M([p-1]) + M([\frac{p-1}{2}]) + M([\frac{p-1}{3}]) + \dots $$

Where $M(x)$ is Merten's function $p$ is any arbitrary  prime and $[x]$ is the greatest integer function. I was wondering if there existed any alternative proofs?

Comment: I don't know if there are any alternate proofs since I don't know your proof, but according to the [Mathworld entry on Merten's function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensFunction.html), Lehman showed that

$$\sum_{n \leq x} M \left( \frac{x}{n} \right) = 1$$

in his paper "On Liouville's Function", but when I checked that paper, Lehman cited it without proof (on pg 315).

Answer (score 0):

> We have $$\begin{aligned}\sum_{n=1}^\infty M\left(\dfrac{p-1}{n}\right)&=\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}\mu(n)\left\lfloor\dfrac{p-1}{n}\right\rfloor\\\\&=\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\\\\&=1\end{aligned}.$$

**Some remarks.** Fix $n.$ Now notice that the term $\mu(k)$ appears in the sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\lfloor(p-1)/n\rfloor}\mu(k)$ if and only if $n\leqslant\lfloor(p-1)/k\rfloor$ so the term $\mu(k)$ appears exactly $\lfloor(p-1)/k\rfloor$ times in $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\lfloor(p-1)/n\rfloor}\mu(k)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty M\left(\frac{p-1}{n}\right).$ Thus $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty M\left(\frac{p-1}{n}\right)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\mu(n)\lfloor(p-1)/n\rfloor=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{p-1}\mu(n)\lfloor(p-1)/n\rfloor.$

Also notice that, for each $1\leqslant n\leqslant p-1,$ the term $\mu(n)$ appears exactly $\lfloor(p-1)/n\rfloor$ times in $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{p-1}\sum\limits_{d\mid n}\mu(d)$ because there are exactly $\lfloor(p-1)/n\rfloor$ multiples of $n$ between $1$ and $p-1$ so we have $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{p-1}\sum\limits_{d\mid n}\mu(d)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{p-1}\mu(n)\lfloor(p-1)/n\rfloor$ and since $\sum\limits_{d\mid n}\mu(d)=1$ if $n=1$ and $\sum\limits_{d\mid n}\mu(d)=0$ if $n>1$ then $1=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{p-1}\sum\limits_{d\mid n}\mu(d)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{p-1}\mu(n)\lfloor(p-1)/n\rfloor.$

Comment: I think you should explain these identities for a better comprehension of the proof.

Comment: Ok @MarcoCantarini. I tried to explain the argument.